# Laravel 8 Schedule Task not sending Email on Cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel

I would like to send an email via task scheduler every minute using Laravel 8.

Below is my code on Kernel.php

```
    $schedule->call(function () {
        $adminController = new AdminController();
        $adminController->test();
    })->everyMinute();
```

On the Admin Controller I have a method called test

```
public function test()
{

    try {
        $fp = fopen('cronJobTest.txt', 'a');
        fwrite($fp, "Testing Started.  ");
        fclose($fp);

        $email = new \stdClass();
        $email->subject = "Cron Job Test";
        $email->greetings = "Hi, Tested";
        $email->message1 = "This is a cron job tester";
        $email->btn_text = 'Test';
        $email->message2 = "";
        $email->url = "dashboard/test";
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::route('mail', 'myemailaddressHere@gmail.com')->notify(new EmailNotification($email));
    }catch (Exception $exception){
        $fp = fopen('cronJobTest.txt', 'a');
        fwrite($fp, "Failed with exception ".$exception->getMessage());
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

On my local machine I then run the command:

```
php artisan schedule:work
```

An email is sent to the provided email address as expected.
[image]

However, after uploading the source code to shared hosting cpanel and setting up the Cron Job, the scheduler does not send an email.

I am sure the method test() is fired because if you look at the test() method, I am creating a file 'cronJobTest.txt' everytime the method is called and appending the text 'Test Started'.

[image]

[image]

In my web routes I have created a route  to direct to the test() method and if I call the method via the route, an email is sent. ie https://mylaraveldomain.com/test

```
Route::get("test", [AdminController::class, 'test']);
```

However the same same method does not send an email if fired from the scheduler.

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a cron in your server? If not, then that is the problem. Refer to [this page](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler).

Edit: Have you confirmed that the cron is running properly? If not, put an everyMinute job that logs something first. Check first if the log shows up.

Comment: I have followed those instructions. I have a cron in my server. I have included logs which are displayed after every one minute. The problem is that the cron does not send an email

Comment: I'm having the same problem, what was your solution?